# create an async await function using delegates in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates

I have the following delegates that I need to make them `async await`.

My delegate:

```
public delegate bool GetUserFromAccessTokenHandler(string token, out User user);

public GetUserFromAccessTokenHandler GetUserFromAccessToken;

public FunctionalOperations(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
      GetUserFromAccessToken = new GetUserFromAccessTokenHandler(GetUserFromAccessTokenFunction);
      _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}
```

Now I need to add async to the method GetUserFromAccessTokenFunction but an error occurs:

```
private async bool GetUserFromAccessTokenFunction (string token, out User user)
{
     var x = await _unitOfWork.User.Get(...);
}
```

The two errors that I get are:

1. `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'GetUserFromAccessTokenFunction' and 'GetUserFromAccessTokenFunction'`
2. `The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>`

How can I fix my delegate declaration to fit my needs?

Comment: "but an error occurs" - Which error?

Comment: edited question

Comment: Both method and delegate return type must be changed from `bool` to `Task<bool>`

Comment: @IvanStoev a new error occurred and that is async methods cannot have ref or out parameters, and I must out a bool and the user, what should I do?

Comment: Don't use out parameters, return it in a combined result, there are oodles of duplicates about this

Answer (score 1):

1. In `async` Methods you can not use `out` or `ref` parameter , [read why you can't](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2f48a52-e35a-4948-844d-828a1a6deb74/why-async-methods-cannot-have-ref-or-out-parameters)
2. `asyn` Method, return specific [Async return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types#:%7E:text=Async%20methods%20can%20have%20the,void%20%2C%20for%20an%20event%20handler.) such `Task`,`Task<T>`,`void`,`IAsyncEnumerable<T>`

your code should look like the following

```cs
using System;   // for Func
using System.Threading.Tasks; // Task Namespace


//...

public Func<string, Task<User>> GetUserFromAccessToken;

public FunctionalOperations(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
      GetUserFromAccessToken = GetUserFromAccessTokenFunction;
      _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}

private async Task<User> GetUserFromAccessTokenFunction (string token)
{
     var x = await _unitOfWork.User.Get(...);
     // ...
     return new User(); 
}
```